# Segue is not working in storyboard after creating navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, segue

Hi I created a single view project and i put a button in the scene that I embed in navigation bar with a bar button on the right to this scene and then I created the second screen which contain an image view, Then I dragged bar button to second scene using Crtl+Drag and choose show action for segue. which works fine.

Problem : Then I created third scene with some image view in it and I dragged the button from first scene with Crtl+Drag to the third scene and choose "show" for segue action.

but when I run the app only navigation bar segue works and the button do nothing.

UPDATE : 
I found why this problem occurs, it's because of stack view constrains. when i put a button or image view in stack view and give it constrain it won't work. but why ?

[image]

any suggestion?

Comment: About the `UIImageView` not responding to actions, you need to set `UserInteractionsEnabled` on it to `true`

Comment: @hannad what about buttons ? they have the same issue is my storyboard

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the problem with them is, but buttons do not need the same handling above. Could you post some more details in the question about the buttons and how you connected the segues?

Comment: In your description, is it the same button you used with the first segue, that has the segue to the third view? If you could provide a screenshot of the storyboard for your test project, that would be appreciated.

Comment: @hannad   no it's another button actually the bar button is connected to the second scene,I've update the post with screen shot.FYI : the scene on the right is the second scene and the scene above it is the third. i connected the first scene which is the middle one with two buttons in it to the both scene.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98096/discussion-between-hannad-and-anonymox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion, your first problems were solved by setting `UserInteractionEnabled` to `true` on the `UIImageView`, and as for the buttons, it seems they were set up incorrectly the first time.